# GitHub Action Release WPF Exe File Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, git, github, yaml

I have the `deploy-TarotTyping.yml` file below.

```
name: "Deploy Tarot Typing"

on:
  push:
     tags:
        - "v*"         
env:
   PROJECT_PATH: TarotType.Main/TarotType.Main.csproj    
    
jobs:
  deploy:
     runs-on: windows-latest
     steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     
        - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
          with: 
            dotnet-version: 6.0.x

        - run: dotnet restore ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }}
  
        - run: dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c Release --no-restore
  
        - run: dotnet publish ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
  
        - uses: actions/create-release@v1
          id: create_release
          env: 
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          with: 
            tag_name: ${{ github.ref }} 
            release_name: ${{ github.ref }}

        - uses: csexton/release-asset-action@v2
          with:
            github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            pattern: TarotType.Main/bin/Release/net6.0-windows/win-x64/publish/TarotType.Main.exe
            release-url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
```

After I publish release to [here (v1.5.0)](https://github.com/eymenefealtun/TarotTyping/releases) and download `TarotType.Main.exe` it simply does not work, and I could not find the problem.

I would be appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my publish folder did not actually consist of a single file. There were a bunch of `.dll` files present. As a result, when I attempted to release the `.exe` on GitHub using GitHub Actions, the application failed to function correctly. This was due to the essential `.dll` files that were required for the proper execution of the `.exe` file. I solved my problem by adding

```
<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> true </IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
```

to the `.csproj` file.

Here is my current `.csproj` configuration:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```